# Where to get StartInfo for a process?

Tags: powershell

Out of 343 processes, not one, zero, nada, have StartInfo. Where can I find StartInfo?

```
PS C:\> (Get-Process | Measure-Object).Count
343
PS C:\> Get-Process | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.StartInfo }
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.8
```

Comment: There is a `StartTime` which might be what you want. I don't think StartInfo works that way. "You should only access the StartInfo property on a Process object returned by the Start method. For example, you should not access the StartInfo property on a Process object returned by GetProcesses" [StartInfo reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I got confused and answered thinking the question was for `StartTime` instead of `StartInfo`. For `StartInfo` it will be only populated if started with `Process.Start`. In Windows PowerShell it is always populated it seems however that output is misleading

Comment: `$x = Start-Process  -Path c:\somepath -passthru`  and then  `$x.StartInfo` will have the data. Just can't get `StartInfo` for other processes it seems.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartInfo

Comment: @ZivkoK, if the `StartInfo` member is NULL, expanding NULL is still NULL.

Comment: @lit Did you test the command at least? Not all properties are pulled from the Get-Process command by default. I'm a bit surprised because NONE of my process are missing this data... So that makes your case interresting

Comment: @ZivkoK, I am interested in getting `StartInfo` for all processes, not just processes started by `Start-Process`.